# shell: can I use linux-like command style `rm tmp/ -fr` in mac

Tags: macos, shell, command-line

Say, I want to remve a *tmp/* dir in shell.

In linux (like ubuntu), I can `rm tmp/ -fr` or `rm -fr tmp/`. But in mac, I can only `rm -fr tmp/`.

Is there any way to config the mac shell (bash/zsh/...), so I can use the linux-like command style: `rm tmp/ -fr`?

Comment: What is that other "UNIX" do you mean. UNIX is a brand, not an operating system (Solaris, AIX, HP/UX, etc. is).

Comment: I clarify it to 'linux' (ubuntu, red hat, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having options after operands as in `rm tmp/ -fr` is non-standard.  IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 has in the section [12.2 Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02):

> Guideline 9:
>       All options should precede operands on the command line.

The implementors of the GNU utilities (as used by most Linux distributions) have chosen to add many non-standard extensions. While sometimes convenient, using these extionsions is inherently unportable. MacOS X has a userland derived from BSD, which does not have most of the non-standard GNU extensions. If you expect to be working with non-GNU systems such as BSD, Solaris or any other commercial UNIX in the future, it really pays to stick to standard syntax of utilities and not get used to any GNU extensions. It saves a lot of hassle when working with all the different UNIX operating systems out there. This is especially true and important when writing scripts. Relying on GNU syntax in scripts will make them unportable.

So instead of installing GNU coreutils on MacOS X, my advice would be to use it as an opportunity to get used to standard syntax (IEEE Std 1003.1, POSIX.2 etc.).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the commands that you use. OS X comes from the BSD family (via NeXTSTEP), and so their standard utilities mostly descend from BSD. There is a large degree of compatibility between BSD and Linux style commands, but every once in a while you run into implementation-specific things like this. If you really want to use the Linux versions of the commands, you can install the GNU coreutils package. It's available from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (recommended) and [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/). In general, though, it's a pain to install the GNU coreutils over the built in BSD toolchain, because of naming clashes and such.

Answer (score 0):

It general it would depend on the implementation of the command you execute. However, as for `rm` (given you mean [rm](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/rm.html)), since you used that as an example, you cannot. At least it will not do what you think.

- `rm -fr tmp/`: will delete directory `tmp/` with the options `-r` and `-f`, so recursive (here mandatory) and forced.
- `rm tmp/ -fr`: will (attempt) to delete directory `tmp/` and/or a file/directory
  named `-fr`, but would produce an error: `rm: tmp/ directory`.

*Note*: the only other way to remove a file named `-rf` would be to use `rm -- -rf`.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I don't have a BSD-like or Linux OS available. However, their respective man pages found only, suggest that it is not even possible there. YMMV.